# Reading more of an RSS Feed with Java

Tags: java, xml, rss, feed

I'm writing a little Java application that I want to use to search RSS feeds for news I care about (I don't really care if such an app exists, I'm writing it mostly for learning purposes). I'm currently using the information I [found here to make the reader](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RSSFeed/article.html#read). The code is great and all, but I've run into a problem. The RSS feeds, like [for example here:](http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml) only go for the last few entries, however RSS feeds like Google Reader show the entire history of the RSS feed as far back as I want. How would I go about reading the RSS feed through to more entries?

Comment: When you 'fetch' an RSS feed you will probably get only those entries in the feed available/published at the time you are fetching. You can store older entries and create a 'history'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the data provided.

Google have the history because they have been polling the feed for a long period of time and kept all the articles that have ever appeared in it.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna have to use an XML Parser to simply go through the recent site archive. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are just another way of formatting content in an agreed upon standard. Each time your application requests the content from the RSS feed URL, a web server processes that requests and returns the content (presumably formatted to some RSS XML standard).

If you want to make sure you don't miss any items, then you will have to poll the RSS feed regularly and keep your own history.

Answer (score 0):

You could go totally nuts since you mentioned learning purposes and use Nutch to crawl and index the RSS content you are looking for, it's actually pretty easy to setup if you run in a single node, not using Hadoop's cluster. You can also use Droid to spider the content.

Or just a simple RSS parser http://www.vogella.de/articles/RSSFeed/article.html#overview_java :)

Comment: If you take a look at my post, that vogella RSS parser is actually what I was using/linking to, but I'm interested: What is Nutch?

Comment: http://nutch.apache.org/ Nutch is a crawler, ala Google Bot. You specify a domain or a list of domains and let Nutch do its thing. It will download all the content for the domains you specified, of course you can get add more configuration to only download from certain url patterns, etc. Then you can write your own plugin to do whatever you want with the content. Very powerful tool...